# Скрипт читает только одну форму на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, form

Сегодня хотел бы обратится к тем, кто знает что делать со скриптом или формой, чтобы при использовании скрипта читалась не только первая форма.
Вкратце:
Делаю кнопку "В корзину" из общего списка, кнопка работает везде, но при нажатии на кнопку добавляется только первый товар на каждой странице.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  $(".add2").on("click", function () {
    let currentProduct = {
        name: $("input[name=name]").val(),
        price: $("input[name=price]").val(),
        id: $("input[name=id]").val(),
        descption: $("input[name=about]").val(),
        count: 1,
        category: $("input[name=category]").val(),
        img: $("input[name=img]").val()
    };

    let locSt = localStorage.getItem("basket");

    if(locSt){
        locSt = JSON.parse(locSt);
        let trigger = true;
        locSt.map(item => {
            if(item.id == currentProduct.id){
                item.count = parseInt(item.count) + 1;
                trigger = false;
            }
        });
        if(trigger) {
            locSt.push(currentProduct);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(locSt));
        console.log(locSt);
    }

    else {
        let newLocSt = [];
        newLocSt.push(currentProduct);
        localStorage.setItem("basket", JSON.stringify(newLocSt));
    }

    $(".add2").notify("Товар добавлен", "success");
  })
});
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<?php echo $row["img"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="about" value="<?php echo $row["about"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">
</form>
```

На сайте генерируется 8 товаров которые берутся из MySQL, формы получают правильные данные для себя, но скрипт читает только 1 форму из-за чего добавляется только 1 товар при нажатии на любую кнопку "Добавить в корзину".
Можно пожалуйста чутка попроще мне обьяснить, а то я чайник…
Тестовая страница сайта с кнопкой (на эту страницу не ведёт ни одна ссылка на сайте)
[Ссылка](http://%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84/testp.php?cat=all&tags=all&page=1)

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что `$("input[name=name]")` и остальные - это первый элемент на странице. А вам же нужно брать "один из", который выбрал пользователь. Измените селектор на правильный и всё заработает

Comment: Если честно немного не понял, что из этого селектор...

Comment: `"input[name=name]"` - селектор